# Converting value type inside class property

Tags: c#

Hi I am having a simple problem, I am trying to convert (value is DateTime and i want to convert it to string) value type inside class to another type, so far i have tried:

```
    private string timestamp;

    public string timestamp
    {
        get => timestamp;
        set
        {
            if (value != timestamp)
            {
                timestamp = (DateTime)value.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss.fff");
            }
        } 
    }
```

But with no luck. Is there a solution for this??

Comment: use `DateTime.TryParseExact`.

Comment: Please be more specific. You have a string property and a string backing field, why are you converting it to a `DateTime` **at all**? If you want a `DateTime` property, why aren't you declaring it as that? In any case, the most obvious problem with the code is that you're trying to convert a `string` to a `DateTime` using a cast operator. This will not work.

Comment: I think this is another "I want a DateTime in a specific format" question.

Comment: What do you think `(DateTime)value.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss.fff")` returns? It obviously casts a string to a `DateTime`. However `timestamp` is a string. Thus your assignemtn fails.

Comment: @DanielA.White since when can a DateTime be assigned to a string?

Comment: @maccettura this code really smells, its hard to know what they want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are converting a string to a string using ToString with a formatter that you would expect on a DateTime, and then you're casting it to a DateTime that has to be assigned to a string.

Obviously, this cannot work.

If you are trying to validate if the new property-value (Value) can be considered as a valid string, then use [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) to verify if the given string is a valid DateTime.  If so, assign the string to the backing field of the property.

```
set
{
   if (value != timestamp && DateTime.TryParseExact(value, 
                                                    "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss.fff",                                                       
                                                  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                                                  DateTimeStyles.None, DateTime out d )
   {
       timestamp = value;
   }
}
```

You will have to fiddle around a bit with the arguments of the TryParseExact method to see what works in your scenario.

Comment: Maybe not say "obviously"? The OP is likely not as skilled as you are. And if it was obvious to them, they probably wouldn't be posting about it.